# How to create a hole in a shape and see through it (drawing of a set square)

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, fill

I'd like to create a drawing that exhibit a way students could construct the tangent to a circle. This implies the drawing of a set square, and I'd want so see the remaining part of the circle in the hole of the set square. Here is where I am, but I'm stuck now. Any help would be very appreciated. If it's possible, I'd prefer a KISS solution ;-) !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
        \node[fill, circle, minimum size=1pt, inner sep=2pt, label={[black, below left]:$O$}] (O) at (0,0) {} ;
        \node[fill, circle, minimum size=1pt, inner sep=2pt, label={[black, below right]:$A$}] (A) at (-60:1) {} ;
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) ;
        \node at (-.8,.8) {$C$} ;
        \draw[very thick, gray, dashed] (O) -- (A) ;
        \node[shift={(30:4)}] (B) at (A.30) {} ;
        \node[shift={(-150:1)}] (C) at (A.-150) {} ;
        \draw[very thick, red] (B) node[above left] {$d$} -- (C) ;
        \draw[very thick, fill=gray, opacity=.5] (A) -- ++(120:.8) -- ++(0:1.6) -- (A) ;
        \draw[very thick, draw, fill=white, opacity=.5] (A) ++(75:.2) coordinate (D) -- ++(120:.43) -- ++(0:.86) -- (D) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh ! I've found the answer, thanks to [jake in "Highlighting part of TikZ figure"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69398/highlighting-part-of-tikz-figure#69405).

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, remember picture]
        \node[fill, circle, minimum size=1pt, inner sep=2pt, label={[black, below left]:$O$}] (O) at (0,0) {} ;
        \node[fill, circle, minimum size=1pt, inner sep=2pt, label={[black, below right]:$A$}] (A) at (-60:1) {} ;
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (1cm) ;
        \node at (-.8,.8) {$C$} ;
        \draw[very thick, gray, dashed, shorten >=-7mm, shorten <=-10mm] (O) -- (A) ;
        \node[shift={(30:4)}] (B) at (A.30) {} ;
        \node[shift={(-150:1)}] (C) at (A.-150) {} ;
        \draw[very thick, red] (B) node[above left] {$d$} -- (C) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, even odd rule, scale=1.8]
        \filldraw[draw=black, fill=lightgray, opacity=1]
            (A) -- ++(120:.8) -- ++(0:1.6) -- (A) 
            (A) ++(75:.2) coordinate (D) -- ++(120:.43) -- ++(0:.86) -- (D) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```